# Eto.Forms async command executed handler not updating TableLayout

Tags: c#, async-await, eto

I am using Eto.Forms for a simple C# application. When a button is clicked, I would like to fetch some data from an API (using Net.Http.HttpClient, which works fine already), await the response, and update some information in a TableLayout.

I have tried the following code. The RefreshClicked method is called, and the debug output prints what I'd expect it to (the data that should be inserted into the table), but the table doesn't change at all. It is also interesting to note that calling `DataTable.Rows.Clear()` from inside the method does clear the table.

If I copy and paste the same code from inside the method into the constructor and use some data for testing purposes, it works as I would expect (inserts it into the table), but not in this method.

```cs
// inside my class
private TableLayout DataTable = new TableLayout();
private async void RefreshClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var results = await GetDataFromApi();

    foreach (Result result in results)
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine(/* results for debugging purposes */);
        DataTable.Rows.Add(new TableRow(/* info from results */));
    }
}
```

```cs
// inside my constructor
Content = DataTable;

var Refresh = new Command
{
    // ...
};

Refresh.Executed += RefreshClicked;
```

There aren't any error messages, it just doesn't update the table. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

Calling `DataTable.Update()` after adding the rows does nothing.

Comment: Could it be that `GetDataFromApi()` is throwing an exception?

Comment: @PauloMorgado no, the correct data is printed by the Console.Out.WriteLine in the foreach loop, so the data is being fetched correctly.

Comment: @CheeseCakeAficionado Show the form itself. This might be a binding issue where the UI is unaware that data has changed. The provided snippets do not provide enough details to properly assess the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll need to call this method:
http://pages.picoe.ca/docs/api/html/M_Eto_Forms_Application_Invoke.htm

put your row-adding and updates in the `Action`